# Reassigning chinese character to a custom character code

Tags: java, android, unicode, character-encoding, bluetooth

I'm currently using UTF-8 as my default charset in Eclipse.

The character code for "**隥**" is **38565** in Decimal Format. I used http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-unichar.html to convert that character to get the Unicode form.

I'm sending out data to a LED Panel using Bluetooth Communication. I used OutputStream.write(**s**) to write out a Signal so that my Microcontroller Side can detect the signal and hence display the corresponding stuffs on the LED Panel, where **s** is a byte ranging from 0 - 255.

Since the default character code for **隥** is **38565**, is there any way possible that I could reassign it to another number? An example would be, I've put **254** as the code to display out this character in my Microcontroller Side.

For the Android side, it is compulsory for me to use 38565 as to allow me to output that character onto an EditText. But when it comes to the bluetooth communication part, how do I reassign that character to another byte?

**Bluetooth Data Sending Code**

```
outputStream.write(5);
Thread.sleep(500);

//Row 1 Message / Scroll
outputStream.write(0); // To indicate to my MC Side that this is TEXT_MODE.
if(sPrefs.getBoolean("scrollRow1", false))
    {

    }else 
        {
        outputStream.write(6); // Scrolling of text
        }
                msg.getBytes();
                if(msg.getBytes().length > 0)
                 {
                    a = 1;
                outputStream.write(msg.getBytes()); //Write the String which is converted to Bytes through the OutputStream of the Bluetooth.
                outputStream.write(32); // Indicate the ending of a String.
                 }
```

As you can see in the above code, Bluetooth is using Bytes as their datatype. 38565 has exceed the byte capacity. So my thought was, when I'm typing the character out on Android App, the key that represent the Chinese Character "**隥**" has a character code of 38565

```
<Row>
<Key android:codes="38565" 
android:keyIcon="@drawable/chinese1" 
android:keyWidth="10%p" 
android:keyHeight="4%p" 
android:horizontalGap="0.5%p" 
android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
</Row>
```

But when it comes to sending the data out to Microcontroller Side, I plan to change the keycode to something else that is within 0 - 255. Is that possible or do I have to make my own charset? I've been trying to figure this out and haven't been able to get any reference or help since the past few days. I hope someone can help me out, I'm doing this for my Final Year Project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm sending out data to a LED Panel using Bluetooth Communication.

The documentation for the panel should tell you what encoding to use to convert your characters to bytes. If the answer is UTF-8, then you would send byte 233 then 154 then 165. If the answer is Windows code page 936, you would send byte 235 then 81. Quite possibly the answer is something else, maybe an encoding such as ASCII which does not support Chinese characters.

```
outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
```

`getBytes` without a parameter uses the computer's default encoding, which likely does not match the encoding the panel uses. In general you should avoid using the default encoding in Java because it varies across machines and is usually wrong. Prefer to explicitly specify an encoding, for example if it is UTF-8:

```
outputStream.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: So are you saying that, a normal ASCII encoding will disable the sending of Chinese Characters? Because on my Panel side, I'm using Array List to form the character on the panel. It consists of 1024 LEDS which I can control it individually. So the output of the LED Panel, is determined by my array list in the MC Side. If I were to send it separately, (233 then 154 then 165), won't it output the character which has a code of 233 and so on? Or do I add it up?

Comment: I used Termite Bluetooth to check what I get from my `msg.getBytes()` when I send through a bluetooth port using the `outputStream.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8));`

I got `e9 9a a5` and the character is this `éš¥` The output is in Hex.

Comment: Yes, ASCII consists of just 128 characters, including latin letters, numbers, punctuation and control codes, but no Chinese. ASCII only goes up to 127, so there is no “character which has a code of 233” in this encoding. Chinese has many thousands of characters so there is no way it can be communicated using a single-byte encoding (max 255). Encodings that support Chinese, like UTF-8 and GBK/cp936, use multiple byte codes to signal a single character. Most assign the codes 0-127 to the same characters as ASCII, then use multiple bytes with the lead in the range 128-255 to encode others.

Comment: Your Termite app is configured to show you bytes as characters using the ISO-8859-1 encoding (or possibly Windows code page 1252 which is very similar). ISO-8859-1 is a Western European encoding that does not support Chinese. There is no particular reason to suppose the encoding used by the LED panel will be the same though.

Comment: So how do I basically link the 3 hex value together to form the character? Because from my understanding, if I were to send byte by byte, won't each byte represent a certain character?

Comment: If the LED panel is using a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8 or cp936, it knows from the first byte how many further bytes are to follow it. If it is using a single-byte encoding you will see three wrong characters. If it is ASCII-only (likely!) you wouldn't see anything. You need to find out from documentation or experimentation what encoding the panel supports. If the panel is not marketed as supporting Chinese characters it probably does not — it's a lot of work/storage to include low-res bitmaps for all the Chinese characters.

Comment: I think I got what you mean already. I did try a character and it worked. I would just send normally from the Android side and when it goes to the MC Side, the MC will the encoding using some code which will collect 3 hex values which will then convert it to the character. Thanks for the explanation and help. It got me going on my project. Cheers.